LoRa point to point communication
I want to setup LoRa point to point communication between two modules. I have 2 NORVI LR406  modules (based on REYAX RYL896) and a Dragino LoRa USB stick. Initially I wanted to setup the communication between a NORVI LR406 and the Dragino but had no success after trying for quite sometime.
Afterwards I also tried with Heltec WiFi LoRa V3 same case for this. At the end I switched to communication between 2 Norvi modules. All of them don't communicate. I tried all these different devices because I thought may be same devices might work because of same hardware and instruction set.
I have searched a lot, followed tutorials for example in this tutorial. The same REYAX modules with simple commands communicated but in my case it didn't happen. Initially both of my modules were lying side by side to each other and later on I also tried at some distance but still didn't have any success. I am a newbie to LoRa and may be doing something wrong. If someone could point out I will be highly grateful.
# NORVI receiver

import serial
import time

def setup_lora_usb(port, baudrate=115200, timeout=1):
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=timeout)
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds to allow device initialization
        print(f"Connected to {port} at {baudrate} baud.")
        return ser
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to {port}: {e}")
        return None

def send_at_command(ser, command, delay=1, read=False):
    if ser:
        ser.flushInput()  # Clear any data in the input buffer
        command_with_newline = command + '\r\n'
        ser.write(command_with_newline.encode("utf-8"))  # Send command
        time.sleep(delay)  # Wait for response
        response = ser.readlines()  # Read all lines from the response
        print("Response:")
        for line in response:
            try:
                print(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                print(f"Error decoding line: {e}")
def main():
    try:
        port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
        ser = setup_lora_usb(port)    
        if ser:
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+ADDRESS=102")
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+NETWORKID=6")
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+BAND=868500000")
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+PARAMETER=7,9,1,7")
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+MODE=0")
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+CRFOP=15")
            print("Receiving message...")
            while True:
                if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                    response = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
                    print(response.decode('utf-8').strip())
                    time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("Failed to connect to the device.")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Dragino LA66
def main():
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    ser = setup_lora_usb(port)    
    if ser:
        # send_at_command(ser, 'AT?')
        send_at_command(ser, 'AT+BW=0,0')
        send_at_command(ser, "AT+RXMOD=65535,2")
        send_at_command(ser, 'ATZ')
        send_at_command(ser, 'AT+FRE=868.500,868.500')
        send_at_command(ser, "AT+GROUPMOD=10,10")
        send_at_command(ser, 'AT+SF=10,10')
        send_at_command(ser, "AT+CR=1,1")
        send_at_command(ser, "AT+PREAMBLE=7,7")
        send_at_command(ser, 'AT+CFG')
        for i in range(5):
            send_at_command(ser, "AT+RECV=1")
        ser.close()
    else:
        print("Failed to connect to the device.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

// ESP32 controller where NORVI LR406 is connected
#define RTLX_RX 0
#define RTLX_TX 25

HardwareSerial lora_serial(2);
String sendCommand(String command) 
{
  lora_serial.println(command);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("\nAttention command sent to LoRa module: " + command);
  String response = "";
  unsigned long startMillis = millis();
  unsigned long timeout = 5000;
  while (millis() - startMillis < timeout) 
  {
    if (lora_serial.available()) 
    {
      response = lora_serial.readStringUntil('\n');
      break;
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Response is " + response) + "\n";
  return response;
}

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Setting up the module \n");
  lora_serial.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RTLX_RX, RTLX_TX); 
  sendCommand("AT+ADDRESS=101");
  sendCommand("AT+NETWORKID=6");
  sendCommand("AT+BAND=868500000");
  sendCommand("AT+PARAMETER=7,9,1,7");
  sendCommand("AT+MODE=0");
  sendCommand("AT+CRFOP=15");
}

void loop() 
{
  sendCommand("AT+SEND=102,5,HELLO");
  delay(2000); 
  // while (Serial.available())
  // {
  //   int inByte = Serial.read();
  //   lora_serial.write(inByte);
  // }
  // while (lora_serial.available())
  // {
  //   Serial.println("Lora serial is available");
  //   String inByte = lora_serial.readStringUntil('\r\n');
  //   Serial.println(inByte);
  // }
}

EDIT 1
Currently I am using both NORVI modules based on REYAX. As both of these will have same instruction set. For sender side I am flashing the code to an esp32 based controller. For receiver I have connected the NORVI module to a serial to ttl converter and Python code is running for that device.



Just a quick guess. Is there any pairing going on here? "... each radio is ‘paired’ (when in Point-to-Point mode) with another radio. Any packets received with the incorrect ID are ignored."

Can you clarify which setup the source code above goes with? Also can you provide any logs/traces returned? Is communication between the host and the modem functional? Note that the Reyax apparently adds its own layer on top of raw LoRa (for addressing purposes at least) and it’s possible it’s the same for the others so you may not be able to mix different modems.

Also remember that in many regions, LoRa has very low send limits (duty cycles, dwell times…) so if you send data to quickly the radio should quickly stop sending data or pausing until it can transmit (which can be a very long time in some cases — duty cycles can go as low as 0.1% and transmit time exceed 1 second…)

@st2000 I dont think so there is some pairing going on. However I have added AT+FACTORY for both transmitter and receiver still no success. Moreover for related to packet id now on receiver side I have added 0 for the destination address and it should now send to all of the device addresses. Also edited the question and added some screenshots.

@jcaron you are right, thats why now I switched to same modules. Both of the modules used are NORVIs (REYAX). Modems respond with +OK, that I will assume they are working. Because for wrong commands or something different I get +ERR.

For region I am testing currently in Germany and here 1% duty cycle rule still applies. I would expect that duty cycle thing should be handled on the program side not on the hardware itself. But still this is an open question which I don' know either. I don't know if its relevant in my case for P2P communication but I have checked (TTN Calculator) the time taken to sent the signal is still a few milli seconds.

What my expectation/understanding is that in P2P, a 'HELLO' message should take less than a second and the communication should be interrupted, still slow thats fine. The duty cycle should be handled on the program side not on the device.

Can you try with a smaller bandwidth? The 868 MHz ISM band is not contiguous and there is a hole between 868.6 and 868.7 MHz. You are centered on 868.5 with a bandwidth of 500 kHz so you are extending to 868.75 MHz which you are not allowed to. Not sure if the firmware correctly checks that but if it does it shouldn’t transmit. Also the duty cycle is indeed 0.1% between 868.7 and 869.2 in the ETSI (Europe) region.

Likewise max EIRP varies a lot in the various sub-bands of EU868, and you are probably exceeding the maximum. With a 2.2 dBi antenna you max transmit power is 13.8 dB + whatever losses you have in cabling. I don’t think the model would block that though (as it can’t know the gain/loss after the transmitter). But you should respect defined limits.

See the post here for a method to detect if the transmitter is actually sending anything.
